# Pure "Select" function over matrix

Tags: matrix, filtering, pure-function

I have several lists of tuples in the following shape:

```
l1 = {{1, 134}, {2, 314}, {3, 164}}
```

I do want to select, from each list, list elements fulfilling a certain criteria. I am using the following pure function for this (applied here to my first list):

```
In[508]:= Select[l1, #[[1]] > 2 &]

Out[508]= {{3, 164}}
```

How can I apply this function to several lists at the same time?

Silly question first: how would you best describe this task? That might help me searching for it in the forums. So far I found no good way of doing it (or possibly have simply not understood it if I came across it).

I would be grateful if anyone could point me the right way. I find the pure function annotation a bit confusing still, so any help is greatly appreciated.

thanks!

mondo

**Edit** addressing Szabolcs' comment: I do have a solution to filter a single list. I want to filter through all my lists though, without having to apply a for loop (if possible).

Comment: Can you clarify the question a bit?  It seems you already have a solution.  Are you just asking what this operation is called?

Comment: [this search](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=Select+condition) will find similar questions on this site.

Comment: @Szabolcs, added edit above.

Comment: [`Map`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html), perhaps?  (Use `Map` to apply `Select` to each list in your list of lists. `Select` does not have a level specification, so you can't do it without some sort of loop.  Maybe some don't think of `Map` as a loop.)

Comment: Thanks Michael - Mapping was what I had in mind, but I couldn't work out the syntax. MikeLimaOscar's answer below is exactly what I had in mind. Thank you all, this has been recurring in my code and given me a headache for a long time...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say that you have several lists of tuples so I assume you wish to map your `Select` to them all like:

```
Select[#, #[[1]] > 2 &] & /@ {l1, l2, l3}
```

If you find the nesting of the slots, `#`, confusing then you could use the explicit form of `Function`, e.g.

```
Function[{lst}, Select[lst, Function[{elem}, elem[[1]] > 2]]] /@ {l1, l2, l3}
```

Comment: Mike, thanks a lot! this is exactly what I had in mind. 

Can you quickly elaborate why I do not need to add indices to the Slots? I.e., why it is not something along the lines of 

    Select[#1, #2[[1]] > 2 &] & /@ {l1, l2, l3}

?

I always found it a bit hard to understand why my original Select function was understood without adding what I wanted # to resemble...

Comment: @mondo Slot indices access different arguments to a particular anonymous function not different levels in nested functions. This sort of thing is clearer when you use the `Function` form.